# PHP (or something else) adding unwanted HTML to my output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, browser

I don't recall ever having this problem but think I've seen it pop up in other web apps, and I've worked in PHP and Ajax plenty of times, so I'm unsure if this is a PHP or browser issue. This is a repost with editing because apparently I lacked clarity.

I have a PHP file, that is literally just:

```
<?php echo 'Hello'; ?>
```

However when loaded in a browser, the actual browser source is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

I am viewing the browser source code, not the inspector. If I set the header to plain text, then it does nothing but make the source code visible as plaintext.

This is a particular issue when I'm trying to call the file via Ajax, as the responseText is the full HTML string when I just want the word "Hello". Tested in Chrome, Opera, Edge & Firefox

The Javascript/Jquery request:

```
function callPhpFunction(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false
    });
    
    var returnedValue = $.ajax().responseText;
    
    alert(returnedValue);
}
```

The result in image form:

[image]

To summarize, I am making an Ajax request via jQuery to a PHP document who's source is a simple hello world output.

The expected result is "Hello". The result I'm getting (via both javascript request and visiting the file directly) is a HTML document. This is happening on every browser, no matter what the echo content is, which makes me think it's PHP or the server doing it, but I really don't have a clue. I've never seen this before

Comment: What webserver are you using? Do you have a `.htaccess` or similar?

Comment: What does `$.post('ajax.php',function(data) { console.log(data) });` show? Also do not use async:false. It is not what Ajax was meant to do

Comment: @mplungjan I'm using async :false for a specific reason, but rest assured I know what the A in Ajax stands for. The result is the same use an async true request. Your code snippet also has the same problem, here is  a screenshot: https://imgur.com/JwZ2I3u

Comment: @Matt I am using XAMPP on Windows localhost. Mostly default setup, there is no .htaccess or other mod rewrites.

Comment: What if you do 

`<?php header("content-type:application/json"); echo '{"message":"Hello"}'; ?>` and `$.post('ajax.php',function(data) { console.log(data.message) });`

Comment: @mplungjan Same thing as when I set the header to plainText - the HTML structure still is created, but appears in the browser window, not just the source code view. The console output is the same: https://imgur.com/a/Ybav5k5

Comment: Possibly this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792866/php-json-response-contains-html-headers

Comment: also worth noting if I set the output to something like `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` then it still adds the `<title></title>` tag but nothing else, so something is just checking for valid HTML

Comment: @mplungjan that could be it. I have had HTML tidy installed at one point, definitely isn't being called in my code but too much of a coincidence. Will investigate.

Comment: Be aware that `ajaxSetup()` sets the values for **all subsequent** ajax calls (and shorthands like $.post). That might lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Just tried this in my local Windows/XAMPP and I don't see this issue. How odd, perhaps as @mplungjan suggests you have a plugin enabled which is doing this

Comment: @mplungjan that was it. tidy.clean_output=On was in php.ini

Comment: Just came to comment that!, found this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.configuration.php